# Validation of viewstate MAC failed

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Message:** Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is
>   hosted by a Web Farm or cluster,
>   ensure that configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation
>   algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used
>   in a cluster. Source: System.Web Inner
>   Exception:System.Web.UI.ViewStateException:
>   Invalid viewstate. Client IP:
>   80.79.116.251 Port: 59340 User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b;
>   Windows NT 6.0) 
> **ViewState:**
>   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...
>   **Stack Trace:** at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception
>   inner, String persistedState, String
>   errorPageMessage, Boolean
>   macValidationError) at
>   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowMacValidationError(Exception
>   inner, String persistedState) at
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String
>   inputString) at
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String
>   serializedState) at
>   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter
>   formatter, String serializedState) at
>   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) at
>   ASP.login_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) in
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\79794658\835d6695\App_Web_h5zykaqc.25.cs:line
>   0 at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I tried suggested solution from this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx
inherit from the BasePage class but I'm still getting occasionally errors above.

I'm using master page and content page so content page inherited from BasePage class.
Maybe someone suggest other working solution?

Comment: Is your application running in a cluster?

Comment: MY application is running on Windows Server 2008, IIS 7

Comment: This doesn't answer my question about the cluster. Do you have multiple web servers or a single machine?

Comment: This question seems like it could be a duplicate. It's hard to close it as an *exact*, however, since there are [over two dozen essentially identical questions...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=validation+viewstate+mac+failed) Perhaps one of those can help? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate machine key and put it inside your web.config 
http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey , that always helps me ;)

Comment: I did generate machine key. but I am still getting these errors. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried playing with batch compile options in web.config, that also resulted with partial success. Don't remember how i solved this problem in the end!